# how can I rename method name for testng

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a testng report. But sometimes, I don't want to show my real method name,like testIntentRecognition below. Can I use something like @Rename("fakename") to rename the method in the report?

[image]

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test {
    
@Test(groups="testng")
    public void testIntentRecognition() {

        System.out.println("test1 from group1");
        Assert.assertTrue(true, "success");
    }

    @Test(groups="testng")
    public void testDocumentRetrieval() {

        System.out.println("test1 from group1");
        Assert.assertTrue(true, "success");
    }

}
```

Comment: Depends on the test framework. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using the `@Test` annotation's `testName` attribute. Here is an example:

```
@Test(groups = "testng", testName = "Custom Test Name for Intent Recognition")
    public void testIntentRecognition() {
        System.out.println("test1 from group1");
        Assert.assertTrue(true, "success");
    }
```

Comment: It works in my idea. But still no change in the report

Comment: hmmm then I don't think TestNG has a mechanism to change the name in the report.

Comment: in fact, I think that you would need to create a custom listener or reporter that intercepts the test method names and replaces them with the custom names you desire. Your listener should extends from `TestListenerAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about testng but junit has an annotation `DisplayName` which allows you to give each test method a different name.